# Finding same numbers in matrix with some conditions

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem for programming competition. The question is easy at some point. I wrote a solution is not working really well. I want your opinion on that problem, how would you manage to solve this kind of problem in more "good" programming.

Question:

> Write a program that will have as an input an N*N array. This array
>   contains integer numbers. You should find how many different numbers
>   are there with the following condition: Different number is also:
>
> A) Numbers that are the same but is next each of other. e.g 1 1   can
>   be thought as one number because are the same numbers and next to each
>   other.
>
> B) The (A) to be true, the if you have for example Number 1, then any
>   SAME numbers at left, right, top and down are also the same.

E.g

```
1 1 2 3

1 2 3 4

2 2 1 3
```

So for the above, there are 8 different numbers. This because, at array [0,0] [0, 1] and [1,0] can be thought as one number and not 3 different. [1,1],[2,1] and therefore [2,0] are also same numbers. So as you can see at the last numbers, [1,1], [2,1] do implies the conditions, and then [2,0],[2,1] also implies the conditions, but because [2,1] also implies the condition with [1,1] therefore all [1,1],[2,1] and [2,0] are one number.

My code:

```
public class matrix
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[][] arr = 
      { 
          {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
          {1, 1, 2, 4},
          {5, 6, 2, 2},
      };

      for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; ++row)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; ++col)
         {
            //top
            if(row!=0)
            {
               if((arr[row][col] == arr[row-1][col]) || (Math.abs(arr[row][col]) == arr[row-1][col]) || (arr[row][col] == Math.abs(arr[row-1][col])))
               {
                  arr[row-1][col] = -arr[row-1][col];
               }
            }

            //botom
            if(row!=arr.length-1)
            {
               if(arr[row][col] == arr[row+1][col] || Math.abs(arr[row][col]) == arr[row+1][col] || arr[row][col] == Math.abs(arr[row+1][col]))
               {
                  arr[row+1][col] = -arr[row+1][col];
               }
            }

            //left
            if(col!=0)
            {
               if(arr[row][col] == arr[row][col-1] || Math.abs(arr[row][col]) == arr[row][col-1] || arr[row][col] == Math.abs(arr[row][col-1]))
               {
                  arr[row][col-1] = -arr[row][col-1];
               }
            }

            //right
            if(col!=arr[0].length-1)
            {
               if(arr[row][col] == arr[row][col+1] || Math.abs(arr[row][col]) == arr[row][col+1] || arr[row][col] == Math.abs(arr[row][col+1]))
               {
                  arr[row][col+1] = -arr[row][col+1];
               }
            }
         }
      }


      for(int row = 0; row < arr.length; ++row)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; ++col)
         {
            System.out.print(arr[row][col] + " ");
         }

         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

My logic is to set the same numbers to negative, and then just count only the positives to find the different numbers.
I want a different algorithm that will yield a smaller Big-O complexity.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but it seems like your example has 8 different numbers:  
`([0,0], [0,1], [1,0]), ([1,1], [2,0], [2,1]), ([0,2]), ([0,3]), ([1,2]), ([1,3]), ([2,2]), ([2,3])`.  
  
Also, when you says you want a "more advanced programming approach" do you mean a better algorithm? One that is faster (smaller big-O complexity)?

Comment: Yes that's right, I will edit my question. Yes I mean a better algorithm, faster one, but also because that are questions for interview etc I want to impress, so I want to change my logical thinking to a better one.

Comment: I asked earlier but deleted it. Can you rephrase your second rule?

Comment: Hey, sure. The second rule says that, if you have a number X then for the rule (A) to be true you should have, left, right, top, or bottom of the X number equal number as X. I don't know if this is better?

Comment: Isn't that redundant?  I'm confused because I see (2) as just restating (1).  Is it just clarifying next to means in all directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can think of it as a graph problem, counting the number of connected components.

For example, make each entry in the matrix a vertex (labelled by row-column), so (0,0) is a vertex (with value 1).  Then, two vertices are adjacent if they are directly above, below, right, or left of one another and have the same value.  For example (0,0) is adjacent to (0,1) because both have value 1.  (0,1) is not adjacent to (0,2) because the first has value 1 and the second value 2.  Then you count the number of connected components in your graph.  Each connected component represents a "different" number.

There are lots of ways to count number of connected components quickly.  For example, start at vertex (0,0) and do a breadth-first search.  Any vertices you find are in the same component as (0,0).  Then repeat starting from any vertex that hasn't yet been found.  Breadth-first search is linear time, but you'll have to run it several times (granted the more times you run it the quicker each run will be) so it's a little complicated to determine the exact asymptotic run time.  Your input size is n^2 (number of vertices).  It won't be worse than n^3 and is probably much closer to n^2 (keep in mind n^2 means "linear in the input size").

Comment: Also thought about the same. The main problem here is to obtain next unvisited "node". If we could afford O(n^2) of additional memory, I'd suggest to sacrifice O(n^2) time first to store all coordinates in HashSet and remove visited "nodes" from it. That will give us amortized constant time for obtaining of next unvisited node between BFS runs.

Comment: Cool explanation. thank you. Yes the problem can be thought as a graph. I don't know very good graph theory so is a bit pain for me to program that. I have to revise my graph theory knowledge.